# Crystal Report Templates & Images not displayed

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using the Crystal report Template into VS 2013.
For that I have used a Web Form & use Crystal Report Viewer into that itself.

the following aspx page code is::

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" 
            runat="server" 
            EnableDrillDown="true"
            HasRefreshButton="True" 
            HasGotoPageButton="True"  
            DisplayStatusbar="true"
            DisplayToolbar="True"   
            EnableParameterPrompt="true"
            HasCrystalLogo="False"
            HasExportButton="True"
            HasToggleParameterPanelButton="true"
            HasToggleGroupTreeButton="true"
            HasSearchButton="true"
            HasZoomFactorList="True"    
            BestFitPage="True"
            AutoDataBind="true" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But getting problem in Displaying Images as shown in the figure below the Icons for button 'OK' is disappeared::

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Open your web.config and insert the following inside the httpHandlers tag:

```
<add path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" verb="GET" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
```

And insert the following inside the handlers tag:

```
<add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
```

Images will start displaying properly in reports.